# Wix API - Refresh Token Expiry?

Tags: api, velo

I am working on an integration for the Wix API. [As the documentation mentions the access token lasts 5 minutes](https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/getting-started/authentication#getting-started_authentication_step-4-app-submits-the-authorization-code), and the refresh token should be used to request a new Access Token and refresh token pair.

However they don't mention how long the refresh token lasts? Am I therefor to assume that unless the App is removed and the permission revoked to the store that a refresh token will last indefinetly?

For example EKM mention in their documentation that refresh tokens last 15 days, but Etsy refresh tokens last 90 days.

Is there anyone with experience that has discovered their lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - as I continued the process to integrate [I came accross another area of the documentation I hadn't spotted before which states:](https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/getting-started/authentication#getting-started_authentication_authentication)

> Note:
> Access and refresh tokens are user-specific. Access tokens are valid for 5 minutes. **Refresh tokens are valid as long as the app is installed on the user's site.**